Add json-c package to yocto sdk
I want to create a yocto sdk for arm64 architecture that includes the json-c library package.
After running 'source oe-init-build-env' in the poky directory, I did the following changes to the local.conf file:
MACHINE ??= "qemuarm64"
IMAGE_INSTALL += " json-c"
Then I ran 'bitbake core-image-minimal' and 'bitbake -c populate_sdk core-image-minimal'.
I see that the package is compiled as native, but I don't see it in the created image, nor in the SDK.
I tried it also with target 'core-image-full-cmdline', but no luck there either.
What am I doing wrong?

To add the package in the SDK, there are 2 commands
TOOLCHAIN_TARGET_TASK:append = " json-c" 

TOOLCHAIN_HOST_TASK:append = " json-c"

might be, you also need to use inherit populate_sdk in your project, please have a look at above 2 commands. I have written it according to kirkstone version. If you are using the dunfell version, please use this command
TOOLCHAIN_TARGET_TASK_append = " json-c" 

TOOLCHAIN_HOST_TASK_append = " json-c"

